# functions operating columnwise on gpuArrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a custom function that takes in a m by 2 matrix (2 columns) and operates on it. 
It's quite a bit complicated function as it involves several matrix multiplications going sequentially through one of the column vectors (in a for loop) and depending on the corresponding value from the other column vector choose the matrix to multiply. 
More like a cumulative matrix product with elements on on column but conditional upon values in one of the column.

eg.,:

```
 col1 col2
 0   0.03
 0   0.04
 1   0.02
 0   0.1
 1   0.004
```

if values are 0, one matrix is chosen to multiply or if it's 1 a different one is chosen.
Then a cumulative matrix product is taken. ie.,
      Values = diag(Valuesmat);
      cumulMatProduct = ini;

```
  for ix = 1:length(col2)
      if col1(ix) == 0
          matrixToMultiply = matrix1;
      elsif col1(ix) == 1
          matrixToMultiply = matrix2;
      end

      anotherMatrixtoMultiply = diag( exp(Values).*col2(ix) );
      cumulMatProduct = matrixToMultiply*anotherMatrixtoMultiply*cumulMatProduct;

   end

  etc.,
```

Basically that's what the function does.

Now, I have a large number of such column data and so would like to know if I could use 
GPU computation with it. ( having access to Matlab r2013A with PCT & a TESLA s2050 )

I would like do something like:

```
    DataMatrix1 = [col1; col1; col1] ;
    DataMatrix2 = [col2; col2; col2];

    gpuDat1 = gpuArray(DataMatrix1);
    gpuDat2 = gpuArray(DataMatrix2);

    [resultVect] = myFuncCall(gpuDat1, gpuDat2, ValueMat,ini); 
     %(ValueMat & ini is not sliced & each processor will have its copy)
```

ie., slice the matrix as columns to each of the gpuProcessor & make each processor use myfunction to give me an output of the cumulativeMatrixProduct for those input columns of data. (more like independent, grained parallelization to cpu nodes/workers but on GPUs)

I don't think the element-wise operations such as arrayfun or bsxfun could be of help here. 
Will really appreciate suggestions and help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you had multi GPU you could use spmd or parfor.

You want a low level access to your GPU resources which you can have only using CUDA and Mex files.

The book [Accelerating MATLAB with GPU Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124080804) might be the right point to start.